# Double Factorial

Tags: combinatorics

I am having trouble proving/understanding this question.

> Let $n=2k$ be even, and $X$ a set of $n$ elements. Define a factor to be a partition of 
>   $X$ into $k$ sets of size $2$. Show that the number of factors is equal to $1 \dot\ 3 \dot\ 5 \cdots\ (2k-1)$.

Lets suppose our set $X=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ contains $4$ elements, i.e $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ then $k=2$ implies $k = (x_1,x_2), \ (x_3,x_4)$ but the numbers of factors equals $3$. What am I doing wrong trying to understand this?

Comment: The three factors are: $$(x_1,x_2),(x_3,x_4)\\(x_1,x_3),(x_2,x_4)\\(x_1,x_4),(x_2,x_3)$$

Comment: @Arthur But isn't that a total of $6$ factors?

Comment: Each line (each pair of pairs) is _one_ factor.

Comment: @Arthur I see now. Thank you!

Comment: Where are the double factorial?

Comment: @Arjang the "double factorial" is the product.

Comment: @Arjang $(2k-1)!! = 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2k-1)$ is written out in the problem text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the $2k$ elements of $X$ be people. We want to count the number of ways to divide these $2k$ people into $k$ teams of $2$ each.

Line up the people from left to right in order of age, or weight, or student number.

The leftmost person can choose her team mate in $2k-1$ ways.

For every such way, the leftmost person not yet chosen can choose her team mate in $2k-3$ ways.

For every choice made so far, the leftmost person not yet chosen can choose her team mate in $2k-5$ ways.

And so on.

If the "and so on" is not viewed as rigorous enough, we rewrite the proof as a proof by induction.  We assume that the result holds for $n=2k$, and prove that the result holds for $n=2(k+1)$. Alicia  has $2k+1$ choices of team mate. For every choice, there are $2k$ people left, and by the induction assumption they can be divided into teams in $(2k-1)(2k-3)\cdot (3)(1)$ ways.  Thus the $2(k+1)$ people can be divided into teams in $(2k+1)(2k-1)\cdots(3)(1)$ ways. This completes the induction step.

**Remark:** In your example, we can list the divisions into teams explicitly. Let the people be $A, B, C, D$. Then $A$ can be paired with $B$, $C$, or $D$. Once this is done the other pairing is determined.

Comment: This does not really answer what is wrong with OP's reasoning. Does it?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I added a remark about the case $n=4$. But the main correction to the reasoning is, perhaps, from viewing a partition more concretely as a division of the people into teams of two.

Comment: Thank you for following up on this, I think it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You can also partition the set as $\{x_1,x_3\}$ and its complement and as $\{x_1,x_4\}$ and its complement. Giving three factors in total.

In general there are always $2k-1$ two element sets containing some fixed element. This observation also suggest a way towards a proof.

Comment: Doesn't $(x_3,x_4)$ make up a factor too?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by that comment, @Robben The partition that pairs $x_3,x_4$ is the same parition as the one that pairs $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @Robben One factor is $\{x_1,x_2\}, \{x_3,x_4\}$ as you said. Another factor is $\{x_1,x_3\}, \{x_2,x_4\}$, and a third one is $\{x_1,x_4\}, \{x_2,x_3\}$. A factor is a set  of sets of two elements.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But aren't the elements distinct?

Comment: What elements? You seem to have a misunderstanding of what a partition is. $\{\{x_1,x_2\},\{x_3,x_4\}\}$ is one partition of the set into pairs. $\{\{x_1,x_3\},\{x_2,x_4\}\}$ is another partition. The third partition is $\{\{x_1,x_4\}.\{x_2,x_3\}\}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ohh, I understand now. Thank you!